# Add other items in the cart page in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to add, on the cart page, below the actual cart, a list of all the other products in the shop that are not added to the cart yet (the shop has a grand total of 5 different products, so the idea is, if the customer has one product in the cart, I show him a list of the other four, to be able to add them quickly from there). Not sure how I'd go about this, do I need to modify the Cart class in classes, so I can get the product list? I'm a bit weary of doing that because of the problems it could cause during updates.

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop is a modular system and you have to develop a new module to do it.